# How could I use a multiple regular expressions to clean a column content in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I want to set multiple regular expressions which when matched, must replace with a certain value. For example, I write a regular expression `re.search('QuickPay with Zelle payment to *', re.IGNORECASE)`, and if matched in a DataFrame column, I want to replace it with 'Payment to *'. I want to have multiple such key value pairs of regular expressions.

As a practical example, if a column has 'QuickPay with Zelle payment to Zack', it should be replaced to 'Payment to Zack'. If a column has 'QuickPay with Zelle payment from Zack', it should be replaced to 'Payment from Zack'. If there is a match for `*DD BR*`, it should be replaced with 'Dunkin Donuts' and multiple such cases. I want this to be done in an automated way where I can just append to the key value pairs and then improve my cleaning function.

I tried using `df.apply()` and `df.replace()` but did not know where to go from there.

Here is some relevant code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

filterMap = {
    re.search('QuickPay with Zelle payment to ', re.IGNORECASE): 'Payment to',
    re.search('QuickPay with Zelle payment from ', re.IGNORECASE): 'Payment from'
}

df = pd.read_csv('./data/data.csv', header=None, skiprows=[0], usecols=[1, 2, 3])

date = df[1]
amount = df[3]
title = df[2]

cleanTitle = title.replace(to_replace=filterMap, value=filterMap)

print(cleanTitle)
```

Comment: any reason you cannot use `re.sub()` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `replace`

```
replace_map = {
    '[Q|q]uick[P|p]ay with [Z|z]elle payment to ': 'Payment to',
    '[Q|q]uick[P|p]ay with [Z|z]elle payment from ': 'Payment from'
}
```

CODE

```
df.replace({'title': replace_map}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

OUTPUT

```
>>> df
                               title
0    QuickPay with Zelle payment to 
1    quickPay with zelle payment to 
2    quickpay with zelle payment to 
3  QuickPay with Zelle payment from 
4  Quickpay with zelle payment from 

>>> replace_map = {
...     '[Q|q]uick[P|p]ay with [Z|z]elle payment to ': 'Payment to',
...     '[Q|q]uick[P|p]ay with [Z|z]elle payment from ': 'Payment from'
... }
>>> df.replace({'title': replace_map}, regex=True, inplace=True)
>>> df
          title
0    Payment to
1    Payment to
2    Payment to
3  Payment from
4  Payment from
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much for this. How do I make the string case ignorant without having to manually type [Q | q] and make the entire thing case sensitive?

Comment: From current behaviour of `df.replace` there is no way to pass regex flags such as `re.I` or `re.IGNORECASE` to the function.

Comment: ```filterMap = {
    '(?i)Quickpay with Zelle payment to ': 'Payment to ',
    '(?i)Quickpay with Zelle payment from ': 'Payment from '
}
``` This fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Created a generic function where you can add more conditions to re.sub() method.
Hope this helps.

```
def replace_clean(text):
 text1 = re.sub('QuickPay with Zelle payment to','Payment to',text)
 text1 = re.sub('QuickPay with Zelle payment from','Payment from',text1)
 text1 = re.sub('DD BR','Dunkin Donuts',text1)
 return text1
df['cleanTitle'] = df['title'].map(lambda x: replace_clean(x))
```